# How to use jQuery ajax and load at button click?

Tags: jquery

I'm not getting response as json type data from server.Please look into my code here...

```
jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 750,
    modal: true,
    buttons :{
        "Search" : function(){
            jQuery.ajax({type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
             url : '<s:url action="part" method="list" />',
         success : handledata})
        }
    }
});
var handledata = function(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

if dataType = 'json' am not getting any response, but if didn't mention anything dataType, getting html format of page.

Comment: Use the callback argument to `jQuery.ajax()`, it receives the return data as its argument.

Comment: Correct john.if i make new question , people put dublicate question like..they will ignore it.

Comment: Yes , i'm getting html page...

Comment: @john , i have created new question. Please see ..http://stackoverflow.com/q/17116412/2480430

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.classloader.').click(function(){
        $('#contenthere').load('/includes/about-info.html');
    });
})
```

Comment: I'm doing these functions in popup window, so really i need ajax support.